# Operation Canceled on async_resolve

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I have minor experience with c++ and facing some issue with boost-asio.
I want to rewrite standard boost-asio async-http-client example  (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/async_client.cpp) in following way.

My goal is to have 2 classes;

1. AsyncHttpClient(that stores host and has member function that will send async calls to specified path).
2. AsyncHttpConnection (that takes io_service, host, path as parameters
   and follows the flow specified in boost-asio async-http-client
   example)

I have the following implementation

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class AsyncHttpConnection {
    public:
        AsyncHttpConnection(
            boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
            std::string host,
            std::string path) : resolver_(io_service),
                                socket_(io_service),
                                host_(host),
                                path_(path)
        {
            tcp::resolver::query query(host_, "http");
            resolver_.async_resolve(query,
                boost::bind(&AsyncHttpConnection::handle_resolve,
                    this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
        }

    private:
        std::string host_;
        std::string path_;
        tcp::resolver resolver_;
        tcp::socket socket_;
        boost::asio::streambuf request_;
        boost::asio::streambuf response_;

        void handle_resolve(
            const boost::system::error_code& err,
            tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
        {
            if (!err) {
                // code here
            } else {
                std::cout << err.message() << std::endl; // GOT "Operation Canceled" here
            }
        }

        // list of other handlers

};

class AsyncHttpClient {
    public:
        AsyncHttpClient(
            boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
            std::string host) : host_(host)
        {
            io_service_ = &io_service; // store address of io_service
        }

        void async_call(std::string path)
        {
            AsyncHttpConnection(*io_service_, host_, path);
        }

    private:
        std::string host_;
        boost::asio::io_service* io_service_; // pointer, because io_service is uncopyable; 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    AsyncHttpClient boost(io_service, "www.boost.org");
    boost.async_call("/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp");
    io_service.run();
}
```

I got an error "Operation Canceled" in this particular way;
If I instantiate AsyncHttpConnection in following way

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    AsyncHttpConnection(io_service, "www.boost.org", "path");
    io_service.run();
}
```

I got everything working perfectly, I think the issue is using pointer to  io_service. How can I solve this issue, if io_service object is uncopyable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void async_call(std::string path) {
    AsyncHttpConnection(*io_service_, host_, path); 
}
```

The body constructs a temporary object of type `AsyncHttpConnection`. So, before the statement completes, the destructor for this type runs.

The default destructor does member-wise destruction. So it triggers the destructor `tcp::resolver resolver_`. The documentation for this class states that any pending asynchronous operation will be canceled on doing so.

In principle the "alternative" `main` has exactly the same problem (and indeed it fails with `Operation canceled` on my box). If it doesn't for you you're getting very fortunate timing of events.

Comment: And here's how I'd idomatically fix it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63a3027add325111

Comment: As suggested in the comments of the idiomatic fix, the operation cannot be initiated within the constructor.  However, the above fix forgets to initiate the operation: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17ffed95d45e69c7

Comment: @TannerSansbury Oops. Good catch